# An alternative to Baileys?

Tags: substitutions, coffee, liqueur

In [this video](http://www.5min.com/Video/Triple-Chocolate-Pudding-Recipe-287389766) of triple chocolate pudding recipe, a shot of Baileys is added to whipped cream. Other than Baileys, what can I add to the cream?

Comment: do you want something non-alcoholic?  Or is some other alcoholic beverage acceptable?

Comment: Are you after an alternative for any parrticualr reason. Almost any liquor can be added to cream dending on your favourite.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're looking for alcoholic alternatives then you could use O'Mara's or some other brand (see [**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_Cream) for a good list).  A light coffee liquer could also serve as a workable alternative.

On the non-alcoholic side, Irish Cream flavored coffee creamers would work well.

Coffee syrups like Monin's or Torani's also have Irish Cream flavors.  I personally like Monin syrups because they're all natural.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much any flavored liquid.  Grand Marnier, bourbon, vanilla vodka, mint syrup, cherry liquer.  Non-alcohol coffee syrups might be an easy flavoring option.  Most cafes/starbucks sell them.

Answer (score 4):

If the alcohol isn't a problem, you could mix some Irish Whiskey with cream and sugar to approximate Bailey's.

Answer (score 3):

Anything. It's just a flavoring agent. If you're alcohol averse, I'd try some mint syrup (if you use mint extract, you'll still be getting some alcohol).

Answer (score 1):

I have found a more delicious option which is far less expensive than Baileys:

Ryan's Irish Cream Liqueur